# Obtain an abandoned domain?

Tags: domains

I tried to purchase a domain name, but surprise-surprise, it's taken. (Just like the rest of the domains I'm interested in.) However, this is kind of unique I think- it's been here for 10 years, from 2012 to 2022, and expires May 6 2022. It's with a provider I've never heard of, and has no files whatsoever. It's essentially just stagnant. Is there a way i can report this? I now see that it says updated in 2021. Not sure what updated means, there is no website associated with it.

Updated Date: 2021-05-03T19:05:29Z
Creation Date: 2008-05-06T18:05:03Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2022-05-06T18:05:03Z

Comment: Just because there isn't a website associated with the domain, doesn't mean the domain is abandoned. Regardless of the registrar, there is no one to "report" it to either, someone bought it and it's theirs' until it expires. You can try to check if there's whois information on the owner, and ask politely if they want to sell it.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran thanks, will do. All the information is redacted unfortunately so I'm going to have to wait until May 6 when it expires and hopefully buy it again. Is there usually some kind of protection? Like the registrar won't sell it in hopes you'll renew it?

Comment: @cloud.mp3 "Is there usually some kind of protection? Like the registrar won't sell it in hopes you'll renew it? " it depends on the TLD.  e.g. .com there is a grace period during which you can renew an expired domain...for a price.

Comment: If somebody has been paying for the domain for the last 10 years, I'll bet that the domain gets renewed again and doesn't expire.   This doesn't sound like an abandoned domain to me.  It sounds like an unused, domain for which somebody has future plans (perhaps just aspirational.)